# Excepciones en Formato Condicional

Tags: excel, formato-condicional

es muy simple pero llevo un par de horas estancado:

| Valor_A_min | Valor_A_Max | Valor_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 12 |
| 10 | 20 | **8** |
| 10 | 20 | **25** |
| - | - | 15 |

Valor_A_min y Valor_A_Max vienen leídos de otra tabla.

Valor_A es input manual en formato general.

Le aplico formato condicional para que cambie de color a rojo y negrita cuando el Valor_A no está entre Valor_A_min y Valor_A_Max.

Hasta aquí sin problema, lo que no sé es cómo hacer para que si el Valor_A_min y Valor_A_Max tiene el campo - no aplique formato a Valor_A.

Saludos y gracias

*Edito:*
Muchas gracias por la respuesta pero no consigo que se apliquen los cambios:
[image: pantallazo de cómo lo estoy aplicando]

Esto es lo que estoy haciendo pero no sé si es correcta la forma en la que lo estoy haciendo.

Gracias!

Comment: Tienes que aplicar todas las condiciones en 1 sola regla, tu mejor opción es la de ´formula personalizada.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es meter una condición que evalúe los datos. Suponiendo que Valor_A_min y Valor_A_Max están en las columnas A y B:

```
=Y(A2<>"-";B2<>"-")
```

Así sólo se aplicará si ambos valores son distintos de  "-".